# framework not found -Xlinker

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm having trouble while running/archiving iOS application and getting linker command failed with exit code 1 error. I already looked around many articles, but still not finding way to fix it.

[image: img1]

None of frameworks added to Link Binary with Libraries section
[image: img2]

And this are the Framework Search Path just as a reference.

[image: img3]

Please ask for the lack of information.
Thankyou.